# AngularJS Http get empty first time

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

I have this code

```
PedidosService.getProductbyID($scope.listProductos.ProductID).then(function (d) {
            $scope.oneProduct = d.data.producto;                
        });
```

PedidosService is the name of my factory, getProductbyId is my http get request and $scope.oneProduct is the variable where i want store the result of this request.

```
factory.getProductbyID = function (id) {
    return $http.get('/Pedidos/GetProduct/' + id);
}
```

factory is my Factory and getProductbyID is my function to call http request

I call this code in a button. The first time that I click in the button, it returns a empty response '[]' but the next times that I click the button, it works fine!!!.

Thanks for you help

Comment: What is the code for your button?

Comment: have you checked the activity in network tab?

Comment: Could it be that `id` is not given for the first call, or different in the next calls?

Comment: The id value is always correct (the first time, too). The activity in network tab is OK except the first time

Comment: This is my code for my button PedidosService.getProductbyID($scope.listProductos.ProductID).then(function (d) {
                
                $scope.oneProduct = d.data.producto;                
            });
            $scope.pedido.Order_Details.push({
                OrderID: OrderID = id,
                UnitPrice: $scope.UnitPrice,
                Quantity: $scope.Quantity,
                Discount: $scope.Discount,
                Products: $scope.oneProduct
            });

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `$http.get` returns a promise because that call is asynchronous. With that in mind a typical call to `$http.get` should be something like this:

`$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

In your context I would have done it this way, so the factory returns a promise and in your controllers you will handle the success and error callback appropriately:

```
factory.getProductbyID = function (id) {
 var deffered = $q.defer();       
    $http.get('/Pedidos/GetProduct/'+ id)
        .then(function (result) {               
            deffered.resolve(result);
        }, function (data) {
            deffered.reject(data);
        });

    return deffered.promise;
 }
```

Comment: He is already returning a promise (`return $http.get(...)`), no need for the $q wrapper.

Comment: Not working. This solution always returns an undefinied value (the first time and next times, too)

Comment: Can you post the result of the API call from the network tab in developer tools? Maybe the problem is elsewhere.